# How to present MovieClip's layers in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, svg

I have movieClips that have 2 frames, each frame has 3 layers, layer for text(caption text), layer for background& layer for  rotatable sprite.

So, the user can drag drop& rotate those movieClips, how would I have the same results in HTML5 ?
Is there a vector engine that can simulate movieClip features (multiple layers, multiple frames) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a bit vague, but there is something called [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS) that might be what you are looking for? Sponsors for that project is Adobe, Microsoft and gskinner.com.

Comment: Wow, that's very powerful, they are using the same function names and classes for AS3 in  javascript, which makes it easy to learn.